# how to proper set if else statement javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

so i have function that will return value based on condition provide, but i notice that it will only return the first function instead of looping through all condition, here is my function

```
const Keterangan = (
        fisikTotal,
        fisikLokasi,
        MaterialFisik,
        TotalSystem,
        LokasiSystem,
        MaterialSystem
      ) => {
        let reason = "";
        if (fisikTotal !== TotalSystem) {
          reason = "Beda Quantity";
        } else if (fisikLokasi !== LokasiSystem) {
          reason = "Bedal Lokasi";
        } else if (fisikTotal !== TotalSystem && fisikLokasi !== LokasiSystem) {
          reason = "Beda Quantity dan Lokasi";
        } else if (MaterialFisik !== MaterialSystem) {
          reason = "Beda Material";
        } else if (
          fisikLokasi !== LokasiSystem &&
          MaterialFisik !== MaterialSystem
        ) {
          reason = "Beda Material dan Lokasi";
        } else if (
          fisikTotal !== TotalSystem &&
          MaterialFisik !== MaterialSystem
        ) {
          reason = "Beda Material dan Quantity";
        } else if (
          fisikTotal !== TotalSystem &&
          fisikLokasi !== LokasiSystem &&
          MaterialFisik !== MaterialSystem
        ) {
          reason = "Beda Material, Quantity, dan Lokasi";
        } else {
          reason = "OK";
        }
        return reason;
      };
```

does anyone here can at least pointing out where i have to improve or any suggestion on how to proper ultilized the function

Comment: I would say if you have more than 3 `if` `else` statement please use `switch` case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should re-order by most restraining condition to be first, on the first match code execution stops and returns instead of continuing.

if this becomes hard to follow, your best bet is to write all conditions in mutually exclusive way meaning:

```
Condition 1
    fisikTotal !== TotalSystem && fisikLokasi = "something" && MaterialFisik = "something else" ...
Condition 2
    fisikTotal !== TotalSystem && fisikLokasi = "differnet" && MaterialFisik = "something else" ...
```

and keep building.

Basically understand which variables your logical flow depends on and write if.then.else in a way that they dont coincide by having all variables for each line making a decision and mutually excluding each condition.